# BibTeX compilation with TeXshop on Mac

Tags: bibtex, compiling, mac, texshop

I have installed TeXshop on my Mac, I can compile my TeX files without any problems. I have also understood how to create a BibTeX file, in saving the file with `.bib`. But when it comes to compile the `test.bib` file selecting BibTeX, it writes whether couldn't find the `test.aux` file, whether that it couldn't not achieve anything.

I don't understand and don't know what to do, 
Anyone has an idea ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: I found that using the same name for the .tex and the .bib file solves the problem since Bibtex needs the .aux file generated by TeX. No idea whether that is proper, but it worked for me in the past.

Comment: first of all, you have to run `pdflatex` or `latex` before running `bibtex`. this way the compiler knows what files are existing. then you run `bibtex`. then `pdflatex` or `latex` twice after that. this ensures all is compiled. you should read on the process on how to create a macro because, you usually run these steps in one go. this comment is far from explaining all nooks and crannies of LaTeX, but it gives you an entry point for further research.

Comment: @Huang_d There is absolutely no need for the `.bib` file to have the same name as the `.tex` file. Many of us have a single `.bib` file which we use for all our documents.

Comment: I do not know the exact order but you need to run LaTeX (or pdfLaTeX) and bibtex (or bibLaTex) multiple times as @naphan mentioned. Texshop may be already configured for this. You may just need find the right button to click.

Comment: Did it work for you https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515807/200866 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bibtex for mac not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225348/bibtex-for-mac-not-working)